# Ideas about integral

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

The problem asks to compute the integral $I := \displaystyle\int_0^\pi \sin^{2n}(t) \cos(2nt) dt$ ($n$, a natural number)

Testing with wolframalpha suggests that $I =  = (-1)^n \dfrac{\pi}{4^n}$

Any ideas on how to prove this ?

(writing $\cos(2nt) =  \Re(e^{i2nt})$ doesn't seem to simplify the computation)

Thanks

Comment: Induction and integral by part may be your friends.

Comment: Alternatively, write both $\sin$ and $\cos$ in exponential forms, expand it (mentally) and note that non-constant terms vanish after integration.